# Saving post_status from WP front end form (WP User Frontend plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to update post_status from front-end form but can't figure out where it goes wrong. No below code saves it as "draft" for post_status. I can't change the select name="post_status[]" because the plug-in generates it automatically.

Front-end form custom field for post_status

```html
<select class="wpuf_post_status_51" name="post_status[]" data-required="yes" data-type="select">
    <option value="private" selected="selected">Private</option>
    <option value="publish">Public</option>
</select>
```

Function in function.php and document for plugin.
http://tareq.wedevs.com/2012/04/how-to-extend-wp-user-frontend/

```php
// Save custom Privacy option to DB
function privacy_post_status( $postarr ) {
    $postarr['post_status'] = trim( $_POST['post_status[]'] );
    return $postarr;
}

add_filter( 'wpuf_add_post_args', 'privacy_post_status' );
add_filter( 'wpuf_update_post_args', 'privacy_post_status' );
```

Comment: what does var_dump of $_POST['post_status[]'] give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checking... why you using []? Selects only accept 1 value so the return is probably a string.

If this is a multiple select (doesn't looks like it) you could try use a foreach:

```
foreach ($_POST['post_status'] as $status) {
    $postarr['post_status'] = $status;
}
```

Or something like that.

**Update: Added parenthesis on foreach.**

Comment: Thank you. it works! the Select generated by plugin and it came with [] even on single value.

Comment: It needs parentheses tho. foreach ($_POST['post_status'] as $status) {
    $postarr['post_status'] = $status;
}

Comment: Hi @Ohsik did managed to get this work?